# Combining sets+tables+windowfunction in one go

Tags: oracle, sas, window-functions

I want to make something like this work in proc sql:

```
proc sql;
%connect_to_sql_macro;
create table sql.table as
(
select some_id, date from connection to oracle
(
select some_id, date, row_number()over(partition by some_id order by date) as row from dataset d join sql_table s on d.some_id=s.some_id 
) where row=1
```

Basically i need to create table in oracle based on dataset joined with oracle table and take the first date for each id.
If i use "from oracle" pass through it doesn't see the dataset, if i make it the other way around i can't use window functions(row_number())  becouse they are not in SAS. For now i create a table from that dataset and then do a pass through but it's large and i need to do it in one go. Any suggestions?

Comment: As you say, SAS doesn't support window functions, so the only way to use them would be to upload the SAS dataset to Oracle first, possibly to a temporary table.  On the other hand SAS data steps can do what SQL window functions do (and more) using _by-group_ processing.

Answer (score 1):

You're probably better off doing it in SAS.
Can be done in one step too

```
libname lib <oracle connection options>;
proc sql;
select some_id
            ,date
from dataset d
inner join lib.sql_table s
    on d.some_id=s.some_id
group by some_id
having date=min(date)
;
quit;
```

or

```
proc sql;
%connect_to_sql_macro;
select some_id
            ,date
from dataset d
inner join (select * from connection to oracle (
               select * from sql_table
               )
            ) s
    on d.some_id=s.some_id
group by some_id
having date=min(date)
;
quit;
```

Also, limit as much as you can the amount of records that are being read from the oracle table.